# TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given) when I try to permute

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras-layer

How shall I permute rows and columns properly in the following example?

```
input_shape = (input_dim, input_features)
inputs = Input(input_shape)
net = Reshape(input_shape + (1, ), input_shape=input_shape)(inputs)
```

net is passed to Conv2D.

When I use inpute_shape = Permute(2,1) I got the error `__init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)`

Thanks!

This is the recent Traceback after I tried some options:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 372, in <module>
    train(model_filename=args.model, epochs=args.epochs, dim=args.dim)
  File "app.py", line 61, in train
    output_classes=reader.CLASSES)
  File "/home/ubuntu/calypso_v2/model.py", line 53, in build_model
    net = Permute(3,2)(net)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Comment: What do the docs for `Permute` say the argument(s) are supposed to be?

Comment: It is a 2D matrix I am passing to a CNN. Before that I am adding a third dimension.

Comment: You should post the complete Traceback.  Do you understand what the exception means? If you haven't already, please read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: I have added the Traceback to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Permute()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/keras/layers/Permute) takes a tuple as its only positional argument. Instead of the tuple `(2,1)`, you've specified the two ints `2`, and `1`.

Try this:

```
inpute_shape = Permute((2,1))
```

Comment: Looks like it is the correct answer but throws back 'Permute' object is not iterable

Comment: It probably doesn't produce that error from *this* line. If I've answered your question, please accept my answer, then open a new question. But before you do, please read and understand [mcve]. Then, in your new question, please provide a short, **complete** program that demonstrates the error.

Comment: The issue has been resolved. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is

```
net = Permute((2,1,3))(net)
```